# Eloquent - Insert data array to table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Heei, I just create some ***booking room*** web with ***invitation people***. The table looks like that

[image]

[image]

data about ***booking room*** will be insert into `jadwal_meetings` table and data about ***invitation people*** will be insert into `invites` table. The controller is looks like below

**Controller**

```
public function save_schedule(Request $save)
    {
      $create = new jadwal_meeting;
      $create->nama_meeting = $save->input('nama_meeting');
      $create->tanggal = $save->input('tanggal_meeting');
      $create->jam_mulai = $save->input('jam_mulai');
      /*and some other field*/

      $id_jadwal = $create->id;
      $create->save();
      // looping email_user
      $emails = $save->input('email');
      foreach ($emails as $email)
      {
        // Insert to invites table
        $email = new invites;
        $email->id_meeting = $save->$id_jadwal;
        $email->invite_people = $save->input('email');
        $email->save();
      }
      return redirect()->route('user_home');
    }
```

and I just create the html *shadow input* element for collect the ***invitation people*** value like this

Html + Jquery

```
<input type="text" name="nama_meeting">
<input type="text" name="tanggal_meeting">
<input type="email" name="people_invited">
<ul class="people_added"></ul>

$("[name='people_invited']").keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.key == 'Enter' && ($(this).val() !== '')) {
        var orang_yg_diinvite = $(this).val();
        $("ul.people_added").append("<li>" + orang_yg_diinvite +"</li>");
        $("ul.people_added").append("<input type='hidden' name='email[]' value='" + orang_yg_diinvite + "'>");
      }
    });
```

Result

[image]

But it's not work, I get error like this

> Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `invites` (`id_meeting`,
>   `invite_people`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (,
>   people1@email.com, 2018-04-26 04:37:50, 2018-04-26 04:37:50))

How to solve this error, please help me :)

Comment: Please check my below proper answer with correction.

Comment: You can not write this kind of syntax: $email->id_meeting = $save->$id_jadwal; this is not valid, cause $save is a Request ibject and $id_jadwal is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making some mistakes. Please try this code.

```
$create = new jadwal_meeting;
$create->nama_meeting = $save->input('nama_meeting');
$create->tanggal = $save->input('tanggal_meeting');
$create->jam_mulai = $save->input('jam_mulai');
$create->save();
$id_jadwal = $create->id;

$emails = $save->input('email');
foreach ($emails as $email)
{
    // Insert to invites table
    $invite = new invites;
    $invite->id_meeting = $id_jadwal;
    $invite->invite_people = $email;
    $invite->save();
}
```

Comment: Wow it's work, really thank you! You save my life :). Thank you, surely! Your code work for me

Comment: How about like this...
`<input... name="aka" />
<input ... name="startHours[]" />
<input ... name="startMins[]" />
<input ... name="endHours[]" />
<input ... name="endMins[]" />`

I'm assuming there are four foreach loop on that. My question is, where to put the save method using one model only?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to change controller code like below.

```
public function save_schedule(Request $save)
    {
      $create = new jadwal_meeting;
      $create->nama_meeting = $save->input('nama_meeting');
      $create->tanggal = $save->input('tanggal_meeting');
      $create->jam_mulai = $save->input('jam_mulai');
      /*and some other field*/

      $id_jadwal = $create->id;
      $create->save();
      // looping email_user
      $emails = $save->input('email');
      foreach ($emails as $email)
      {
        // Insert to invites table
        $invite = new invites;
        $invite->id_meeting = $id_jadwal; // changes
        $invite->invite_people = $email; // changes
        $invite->save();
      }
      return redirect()->route('user_home');
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: @aj3sh - Thanks, dude. :-)